# Does TensorFlow.js use the GPU for computations?

Tags: javascript, tensorflow, tensorflowjs

The official documentation of TensorFlow.js mentions that it uses WebGL for accessing the GPU. Is WebGL only used for rendering or for computations also?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Not quite sure what you mean by rendering. To my knowledge tfjs doesnt do any rendering..

Yes, WebGL is used for computations